# Haskell Language Report: definition of reservedid

Tags: haskell, syntax

OK, so I've spent all day playing with the Haskell Language Report (2010), and finding all sorts of "interesting" edge-cases. Stuff that you'd *think* should be an error, but which is actually allowed.

In particular, consider the following excerpt from the lexical syntax reference (section 10.2):

```
reservedid → case | class | data | default | deriving | do | else
           | foreign | if | import | in | infix | infixl |
           | infixr | instance | let | module | newtype | of
           | then | type | where | _
```

You *might* expect to see `qualified` in that list… But it isn't there. (Nor is `as` or `hiding`, for that matter.)

Now I'm wondering… Is this an accidental oversight in the Report? Or is this a deliberate design decision?

It appears that GHC at least follows the letter of the specification, for it will cheerfully allow you to define a variable who's name is, in fact, `qualified`. Weird, but true. So it seems that this name is only "special" on one context. By contrast, you can *never* name a variable `module`. We could have made this word special only at the start of the file… but we didn't.

Comment: Interestingly, it appears that StackOverflow doesn't consider `foreign` to be a keyword... (Mind you, I don't know which language it has auto-detected, so...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`qualified`, `as` and `hiding` only occur in specific places as keywords, thus can be used as variable names.

- `qualified` only occurs after `import`.
- `as` only occurs after `import qualified PACKAGE`
- `hiding` only occurs after `import [qualified] PACKAGE [as NAME]`

I see what you mean when you point out that `module` could be one of these placement-specific keywords, but it seems counter-intuitive to name anything `module`. Maybe a previous version of Haskell allowed multiple modules in one file?

One could say the same for `qualified` and `hiding`, but I've used `as` a lot, like so:

```
zip [] _  = []
zip _  [] = []
zip (a:as) (b:bs) = (a, b) : zip as bs
```

So, with that in mind, I think it is indeed a design decision, one that I think a lot of languages* could do with including.

It might be worth pointing out that `deriving` could be one of these words, because it always follows a data declaration, as well as `foreign`, because it's only reserved with the FFI extension.

---

**especially javascript, with it's [huge list of mainly pointless reserved words](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp)!*

Comment: I often find myself trying to use `if` and `of` for in-file and out-file. Obviously, that fails miserably... ;-)

Comment: It's not so much that they can only appear in specific places, but that no *ordinary* identifier can appear in the same places. `module`, `deriving` and `foreign` all break that.

Answer (score 4):

First, the keywords "as", "hiding", and "qualified" were not in the original definition of Haskell.  When they were added they were not made into reserved words for the sake of backwards compatibility.  Adding reserved words is a sure way to break code.  It was a very deliberate decision.

Second, as far as I know Haskell does not forbid multiple modules per file.  The specification simply does not talk about files.  (But I don't know of any implementation that allows it.)

Comment: Most particularly, `as` is the plural of `a`. I'm sure somebody somewhere has used that.